# Создание собственной карты Яндекс JS API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Согласно [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map), сделал собственную карту, теперь пытаюсь по клику узнать координаты точки, но там задано, что начальные координаты [0,0], не могу понять как получить настоящие координаты объекта и задать координаты метки не [0,0], а настоящие координаты. Карту наложил идентичную, 1 в 1 как яндекс карта, указал размеры изображения, центр и т.п.
Добавил код для получения координат клика:

```
map.events.add('click', function (e) {
    if (!map.balloon.isOpen()) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        map.balloon.open(coords, {
            contentHeader:'Событие!',
            contentBody:'<p>Координаты щелчка: ' + [
                coords[0].toPrecision(6),
                coords[1].toPrecision(6)
            ].join(', ') + '</p>',
            contentFooter:'<sup>Щелкните еще раз</sup>'
       });
    }
    else {
        map.balloon.close();
    }
});
```

Но выводит снова относительно [0,0]

Полный код js:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {

    var LAYER_NAME = 'user#layer',
        MAP_TYPE_NAME = 'user#customMap',
        // Директория с тайлами.
        TILES_PATH = 'images/tiles',
        /* Для того чтобы вычислить координаты левого нижнего и правого верхнего углов прямоугольной координатной
         * области, нам необходимо знать максимальный зум, ширину и высоту изображения в пикселях на максимальном зуме.
         */
        MAX_ZOOM = 16,
        PIC_WIDTH = 2303,
        PIC_HEIGHT = 1793;

    /**
     * Конструктор, создающий собственный слой.
     */
    var Layer = function () {
        var layer = new ymaps.Layer(TILES_PATH + '/%z/tile-%x-%y.png', {
            // Если есть необходимость показать собственное изображение в местах неподгрузившихся тайлов,
            // раскомментируйте эту строчку и укажите ссылку на изображение.
            // notFoundTile: 'url'
        });
        // Указываем доступный диапазон масштабов для данного слоя.
        layer.getZoomRange = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve([16, 19]);
        };

        return layer;
    };
    // Добавляем в хранилище слоев свой конструктор.
    ymaps.layer.storage.add(LAYER_NAME, Layer);

    /**
     * Создадим новый тип карты.
     * MAP_TYPE_NAME - имя нового типа.
     * LAYER_NAME - ключ в хранилище слоев или функция конструктор.
     */
    var mapType = new ymaps.MapType(MAP_TYPE_NAME, [LAYER_NAME]);
    // Сохраняем тип в хранилище типов.
    ymaps.mapType.storage.add(MAP_TYPE_NAME, mapType);

    // Вычисляем размер всех тайлов на максимальном зуме.
    var worldSize = Math.pow(2, MAX_ZOOM) * 256,
        /**
         * Создаем карту, указав свой новый тип карты.
         */
        map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [54.8203484673016, 58.4527116836493],
            zoom: 0,
            controls: ['zoomControl'],
            type: MAP_TYPE_NAME,
        }, {

            // Задаем в качестве проекции Декартову. При данном расчёте центр изображения будет лежать в координатах [0, 0].
            projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT / 2 - worldSize, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, worldSize - PIC_WIDTH / 2]], [false, false]),
            // Устанавливаем область просмотра карты так, чтобы пользователь не смог выйти за пределы изображения.
            restrictMapArea: [[-PIC_HEIGHT / 2, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, PIC_WIDTH / 2]]

            // При данном расчёте, в координатах [0, 0] будет находиться левый нижний угол изображения,
            // правый верхний будет находиться в координатах [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH].
            // projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT - worldSize, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, worldSize]], [false, false]),
            // restrictMapArea: [[0, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH]]
        });

    // Ставим метку в центр координат. Обратите внимание, координаты метки задаются в порядке [y, x].
    var point = new ymaps.Placemark([55.75370903771494, 37.61981338262558], {
        balloonContent: 'Координаты метки:'
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#darkOrangeDotIcon'
    });


    map.events.add('click', function (e) {
        if (!map.balloon.isOpen()) {
            var coords = e.get('coords');
            map.balloon.open(coords, {
                contentHeader: 'Событие!',
                contentBody: '<p>Координаты щелчка: ' + [
                    coords[0].toPrecision(6),
                    coords[1].toPrecision(6)
                ].join(', ') + '</p>',
                contentFooter: '<sup>Щелкните еще раз</sup>'
            });
        }
        else {
            map.balloon.close();
        }
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(point);
});
```

Comment: Пока вы не покажите полностью то что вы сделали, непонятно как вам помочь. По коду который вы приложили всё выглядит нормально.

Comment: Полный код в документации - песочнице, ничего не вырезано и добавлен только код, который выше. Изменены тайлы карты и центр карты. Пусть будет [55.75370903771494, 37.61981338262558] центр Москвы. Ссылка https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map

Comment: А какие координаты вы хотите получить, координаты которые будут соответствовать клику по карте? Какие тайлы используются? От проекции тайлов зависит то как будут возвращаться координаты.

Comment: скачал область яндекс карты, нарезал тайлы согласно инструкции (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/ymapstiler-docpage/). Координаты хочу получить такие, что если я нажал на мавзолей Ленина, то вернулись общепринятые широта: 55.75370903771494 долгота: 37.61981338262558.
Т.е. я наложил свою карту на обычную карту, координаты, по моему мнению, должны совпадать, просто я хочу видеть свою карту, что то рисовать на ней допустим, но координаты остаются прежними

Comment: "скачал область яндекс карты, нарезал тайлы согласно инструкции (tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/…)." Зачем такие сложности, тем более что это запрещено? Почему вы не хотите просто наложить свою карту поверх, как например в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_with_image ?

Comment: это печально.. Хотел сделать карту без "Пяторочек" и прочего мусора

Comment: Видоизменять тайлы Яндекса нельзя.